# 1d cnn for frequency domain data

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use 1D CNN for frequency domain data, where each data point is a vector of length 300. How should I mention the input shape in Keras conv1D. How should my training data be reshaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to check the following link for 1D conv example.

https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2017/04/02/a-simple-convolutional-neural-network-for-the-binary-outcome/

The dataset used in his example:
https://mega.nz/#!wt5UEKaZ!AY12J0-kcRE0kMsuHskupkmKa0LUYVsFjlmdq1LCkus

Answer (score 0):

I will use example from the computer vision.

Lets assume your input is an image of m X n X 10 and you use 4 1D conv filters then the output would be m X n X 4. 1D convolution is used to compress (bottleneck) across depthwise.

If you are using a vector of 300 with t 1D convolution filters. You would get 300 X t output but that would be of no use.

But if the input is of the format 1X1X300 with t (t<300) 1 D convolution filters then you would get 1X1Xt output which means you had compressed or bottlenecked the information from 300 dimensions to t dimensions. That looks of some use.